# VBA Query returning nulls

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using the query builder in Access I am able to find the total, but I need to find the total using the vba code builder. The code given here gives me a null value.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbs As Database
Dim strSQL As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb


strSQL = "SELECT Sum(GiftRcvd.Rcvdamount) AS SumOfRcvdamount FROM OurEvents INNER JOIN GiftRcvd ON OurEvents.EventName = GiftRcvd.EventName " & _
"WHERE ((([OurEvents].[EventDate])>" & Me.DateFrom.Value & " And ([OurEvents]![EventDate])< " & Me.DateTo.Value & "));"

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

SumOfRcvdamount = rst![SumOfRcvdamount]

MsgBox SumOfRcvdamount
```

Comment: You might want to verify that `Me.DateFrom` and `Me.DateTo` both have values. It's likely that your query is returning an empty recordset, which would return Nulls for the values.

Comment: You might also check how the value is represented in the SQL.  As I remember, date literals need to be bracketed with "#".  A clause like `EventDate > 1/30/2019` might not work as a date: it has to be `EventDate > #1/30/2019#`.  BUT, this is from memory.

Comment: Ann L: That did the trick. I just updated my query with your suggestion.

Comment: Well, then, if I turn it into an answer, will you mark it as accepted?

Comment: You might want to edit your question back to the original form (unless you're still having problems!)  Now that it includes the `#` marks, it suggests that the absence of `#` *wasn't* the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your query is returning an empty recordset. Assuming you have data, this most likely means that your `HAVING` clause is filtering out the records you want.

As I remember, date literals in Access have to be in the format `#1/30/2019#`:  a clause in the form `[EventDate] > 1/30/2019` will not evaluate the way you want.

So try bracketing those date parameters with `#`:

```
[OurEvents].[EventDate])> "#" & Me.DateFrom.Value & "#"
```

Strictly speaking, you should avoid assembling queries from strings (due to the possibility of SQL Injection attacks): you should instead parameterize them and pass parameter values.  BUT, that's harder to do in Access than in other forms of SQL.

Comment: I have changed the code as following: strSQL = "SELECT Sum(GiftRcvd.Rcvdamount) AS SumOfRcvdamount FROM OurEvents INNER JOIN GiftRcvd ON OurEvents.EventName = GiftRcvd.EventName " & _
    "WHERE ((([OurEvents].[EventDate])> #" & Me.DateFrom.Value & "# And ([OurEvents]![EventDate])< #" & Me.DateTo.Value & "#));"

Comment: And that will fail in a non-US (International) environment.

Comment: Good point! So would you recommend a parameterized query to which actual Date objects are passed?

Comment: At any time. But you could also first pass the control values to variables of data type _Date_, then use the formatted expressions (as shown) of these in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to format your date values to valid `string expressions`:

```
"WHERE ((([OurEvents].[EventDate])> #" & Format(Me.DateFrom.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And ([OurEvents]![EventDate])< #" & Format(Me.DateTo.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#));"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more 'secure' to use the international standard date notation `yyyy-mm-dd` instead of `yyyy/mm/dd`?

Comment: It would be the same. Just don't use a plain slash as it will be read as the localised date separator, not a literal slash.